# How to avoid 404 error in Twitter API's Unlike Tweet endpoint?

Tags: twitter

I am attempting to Unlike a Tweet using Pipedream an integration platform. When I hit Twitter's API for Unlike a Tweet, I get an 404. I double checked and the URL is the same as in the documentation.

```
const body = {
    config: {
        method: "post",
        url: `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/favorites/destroy.json`,
        params : {  
            id : params.id,
            include_entities : params.include_entities
        },
    },
    token: {
        key: auths.twitter.oauth_access_token,
        secret: auths.twitter.oauth_refresh_token,
    }
};
```

As you can see, the URL from that code is the one specified in the documentation at https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/tweets/post-and-engage/api-reference/post-favorites-destroy

Any advice on how to get this corrected?

Comment: Are you sure that the Tweet ID you’re passing as a parameter is correct? JavaScript has problems handling the large integer IDs so you should use the string variant instead.

Comment: hi @AndyPiper, your suggestion was correct. I had to use send the id as a string, instead of a number. we tried to use BigInt but this didn't serialize in the Pipedream platform, so using string was the right workaround. not sure if you want to post your comment as an answer, and I'll mark it as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure that the Tweet ID you’re passing as a parameter is correct? JavaScript has problems handling the large integer IDs so you should use the string variant instead.

Answer (score -1):

Here's my code to get around that

```
for (User users : Spigot.getUsers()) {
    if (users.getKnowledgeLevel(KnowledgeTopic.JAVA_CODING) <= 5) {
        users.getPlayer().getInventory().addItem(new ItemStack(Material.JAVA_BOOK, 1));
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer looks unrelated to the question. Maybe you posted to the wrong question?